# Autocomplete not working using dynamic html

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

Iam adding html for input tag dynamically through enterPerson() and then calling  onkeyup=changeOnType(this) which on echoing $results in autoInvit.php should display autocomplete, but WHY does my autocomlete code does not work,infact data shows if I alert it. can any one please help me out ?
Thank you in advance :)

header files for jquery and autocomplete:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />  
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

autocomplete in "main.php" :

```
<script>    
function changeOnType(x){

    $.post(
    "autoInvit.php",
    {
         vals: $(x).val()
    },
    function(data){

    $("#"+x.id).autocomplete( {source:"autoInvit.php" }  );

    //alert(data);  
    }
    );

}
</script>
```

here's the dynamic html's php code in "invities.php":

```
<?php 

echo '<input class="e" type="email" id="email"  onkeyup="changeOnType(this)"  autocomplete="on" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true"  />';
?>
```

Here's my php file "autoInvit.php" which echos the result:

```
 <?php

    include("includes/connection.php"); 

    $value = strip_tags($_POST['vals']);

    $req = "SELECT email as name "
        ."FROM members "
        ."WHERE email LIKE '".$value."%' "; 


    $query = mysql_query($req);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $results[] = $row['name'];
    }


    echo json_encode($results);

    ?>
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to make the `post` request. **Edit**: There's no need to call a separate function or attach a listener to the input, just register the autocomplete plugin. This will need to be called once the DOM is ready, so you will need to wrap it in a ready function. This should be all the javascript you need:

```
$(function() {
    $("#"+x.id).autocomplete( {source:"autoInvit.php" }  );
});
```

What the user has typed will be passed with the request as the parameter `term`

From the jQuery docs for [autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/):

> String: When a string is used, the Autocomplete plugin expects that
>   string to point to a URL resource that will return JSON data. It can
>   be on the same host or on a different one (must provide JSONP). The
>   Autocomplete plugin does not filter the results, instead a query
>   string is added with a term field, which the server-side script should
>   use for filtering the results. For example, if the source option is
>   set to "http://example.com" and the user types foo, a GET request
>   would be made to http://example.com?term=foo. The data itself can be
>   in the same format as the local data described above.

Also, you'll want to be careful when passing content from the user directly to the DB. You can open yourself to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).